# Openssl keeps prompting for a phrase during key generation

Tags: apache2, openssl, certificates

I am following the directions that are published on the Ubuntu site. First, it asks you to create a secure key, then it tells you to enter `openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key.insecure` to create the insecure key.

My issue occurs during the creation of the insecure key, it is still insisting that I chose a pass phrase.

My very limited understanding is that I need an insecure key to work with apache2.

I took a look at the man page and I don't see the `-in` command line option documented. Is that the correct switch to generate an insecure key?

Also, should I be sudo when I create these keys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was right there in the directions, I just didn't read far enough.

`openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr` creates the file I need for apache2.